# ReactJS for editing comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, components

I'm trying to figure out how to edit comments in ReactJS. I have been following [this tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html).

There are several theories I have on the solution:

- Using mutable `state` instead of immutable `props`.
- Has to do with the `CommentBox` component which has the `loadCommentsFromServer` and `handleCommentSubmit` functions. The `loadComments` function fires an AJAX request, possibly to my `comments.json` file.

Here's the relevant code from the `server.js` file

```
var COMMENTS_FILE = path.join(__dirname, 'comments.json'); 

app.get('/api/comments', function(req, res) { 
   fs.readFile(COMMENTS_FILE, function(err, data) { 
     if (err) { /* Print error to console */ } 
     res.json(JSON.parse(data)); 
   }); 
 }); 

// This snippet of code is probably the most important
 app.post('/api/comments', function(req, res) { 
   fs.readFile(COMMENTS_FILE, function(err, data) { 
     if (err) { /* Print error to console */ }
     var comments = JSON.parse(data); 

     var newComment = { 
       id: Date.now(), 
       text: req.body.text, 
     }; 
     comments.push(newComment); 
     fs.writeFile(COMMENTS_FILE, JSON.stringify(comments, null, 4), function(err) { 
       if (err) { /* Print error to console */ }
       res.json(comments); 
     }); 
   }); 
 });
```

Here's my main script file where I generate react components

```
var Comment = React.createClass({ 

   render: function() { 
     return ( 
       <div className="comment"> 
         // Trying to change the value of the text box on edit
         <p onChange={this.handleTextChange()}> {this.props.text} </p> 
       </div> 
     ); 
   } 
 }); 

 var CommentBox = React.createClass({
```

When the component is first created, we need to get `JSON` data from the server and update the `state` with the latest data. `this.setState()` allows for dynamic updates. The old array of comments is being replaced by the new one

```
   loadCommentsFromServer: function() { 
     $.ajax({ 
       url: this.props.url, 
       dataType: 'json', 
       cache: false, 
       success: function(data) { 
         this.setState({data: data}); 
       }.bind(this), 
       error: function(xhr, status, err) { 
         console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString()); 
       }.bind(this) 
     }); 
   },
```

This function passes data from the child components up to the parent components. It's supposed to submit to the server and refresh the list of comments

```
   handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) { 
     var comments = this.state.data; 
     comment.id = Date.now(); 
     var newComments = comments.concat([comment]); 
     this.setState({data: newComments}); 
     $.ajax({ 
       url: this.props.url, 
       dataType: 'json', 
       type: 'POST', 
       data: comment, 
       success: function(data) { 
         this.setState({data: data}); 
       }.bind(this), 
       error: function(xhr, status, err) { 
         this.setState({data: comments}); 
         console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString()); 
       }.bind(this) 
     }); 
   }, 
   getInitialState: function() { 
     return {data: []}; 
   }, 
   componentDidMount: function() { 
     this.loadCommentsFromServer(); 
     setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval); 
   }, 
   render: function() { 
     return ( 
       <div className="commentBox"> 
         <h1>Comments</h1> 
         <CommentList data={this.state.data} /> 
         <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} /> 
       </div> 
     ); 
   } 
 }); 

 var CommentList = React.createClass({ 
   render: function() { 
     var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) { 
       return <Comment key={comment.id}>{comment.text}</Comment>  
     }); 
     return <div className="commentList"> {commentNodes} </div> 
     ); 
   } 
 });
```

Here a component is being created for filling out forms. `this.state` is used to save user's input as it's entered. I'm trying to accomplish this with the edit functionality.

```
 var CommentForm = React.createClass({ 
   getInitialState: function() { 
     return {text: ''}; 
   }, 
   handleTextChange: function(e) { 
     this.setState({text: e.target.value}); 
   }, 
   // This is also probably an important function
   handleSubmit: function(e) { 
     e.preventDefault(); 
     var text = this.state.text.trim(); 
     this.props.onCommentSubmit({text: text}); 
     this.setState({text: ''}); 
   },
```

The `value` property of the input elements will reflect the state of the component and attach `onChange` handlers to them

```
   render: function() { 
     return ( 
       <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 
         <input type="text" value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleTextChange} /> 
         <input type="submit" value="Post" /> 
       </form> 
     ); 
   } 
 });
```

Finally, I am rendering the `CommentBox` component. The url attribute fetches dynamic data from the server. The `pollInterval` reloads the page every 2 seconds.

```
 ReactDOM.render( 
   <CommentBox url="/api/comments" pollInterval={2000} />, 
   document.getElementById('content') 
 );
```

Here were my thoughts on how to implement the edit functionality

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.edit').on('click', function() {
        $(this).prev().prop('contentEditable', 'true');
        $(this).prev().focus();
    });
},1000);
```

I had to use `setTimeout` because it would take some time before the component's file to be loaded. I would then listen for clicking on the edit button, and change the html5 `contentEditable` property to true.

The problem I have is in updating the changes to the JSON file once it's edited.

I'd also like to know if there's a more react way of accomplishing this onclick functionality

As you can see in my component's file, I added an `onChange` handler to the paragraph that renders the body of the text.

```
render: function() { 
  return ( 
    <div className="comment"> 
      <p onChange={this.handleTextChange()}> {this.props.text} </p> 
    </div>  
  ); 
}
```

I've searched the internet extensively for examples of editing functionality but couldn't find anything.

My goal was to make this code as readable as possible. I tried to trim down code that is not immediately relevant to the problem at hand. I have removed the following code:

- Declaration of npm variables and `app.use`
- The listening of the server
- The author fields for the text form. We only need the text field

Comment: any suggestions on how to improve this post? I only want to have the relevant information so it's easiest to solve the problem

Comment: What is your actual question? You have many blocks of code and text, but not a single question mark to be seen anywhere.  If you have a problem in there somewhere, state clearly what it is.

Answer (score 4):

It's usually not a very good idea to have jQuery mucking with React components (though jQuery + React can play nice with each other for certain tasks); we are running a large scale React application and have spent many hours removing instances of this from our early days.

In terms of saving the comments, you need a new endpoint to handle that functionality, it should look almost exactly like `app.post('/api/comments')` except instead of getting `data` from reading the file, it should get data from `req.body`, which is the data posted to it. To keep the same url `this.props.url` you could set it up as a PATCH endpoint: `app.patch('/api/comments' ...)`. I'll leave that implementation up to you. The React save functionality should happen like this: the `Comment` component should use state to manage it's...state. Clicking "Edit" should switch that state to have the `contentEditable` set to true, "Edit" become "Save", etc. The actual saving part should be defined in the parent component `CommentBox` and should be passed down to the `Comment` component. Here is a basic idea of the changes you should make to allow editing, it's 100% untested but hopefully helps out some.

```
// changes to Comment component
var Comment = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      contentEditable: false,
      buttonText: 'Edit',
      text: this.props.text
    };
  },
  handleButton: function() {   
    var commentTag = this.refs.comment;
    // if the component is currently editable and the text is different from the original, save it
    if (this.state.contentEditable && commentTag.textContent != this.state.text) {
      this.props.onUpdateComment(this.props.id, commentTag.textContent);
    }
    // invert current contentEditable state Save => Edit or Edit => Save
    var editable = !this.state.contentEditable;
    this.setState({
      contentEditable: editable,
      // update the state to reflect the edited text
      text: commentTag.textContent,
      // change button text based on editable state
      buttonText: editable ? 'Save' : 'Edit'
    });
 },
 render: function() {
   return (
     <div className="comment">
       <h2 className="commentAuthor">{this.props.author}</h2>
       <p ref="comment" contentEditable={this.state.contentEditable}>{this.state.text}</p>
       <button onClick={this.handleButton}>{this.state.buttonText}</button>
     </div>
   );
 }
});

// changes to CommentList
var CommentList = React.createClass({ 
   render: function() { 
     var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) { 
       return <Comment onUpdateComment={this.props.onUpdateComment} {...comment} />  
     }); 
     return ( 
       <div className="commentList"> 
         {commentNodes} 
       </div> 
     ); 
   } 
 });

 // changes to CommentBox
 var CommentBox = React.createClass({
   loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
     $.getJSON(this.props.url)
      .then(function(newComments) {
        this.setState({ data: newComments });
      }.bind(this))
      .fail(function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      });
   }, 
   handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) { 
     var comments = this.state.data; 
     comment.id = Date.now(); 
     var newComments = comments.concat([comment]); 
     this.setState({data: newComments}); 

     $.post(this.props.url, comments)
      .then(function(data) {
        this.setState({ data: data });
      }.bind(this))
      .fail(function(xhr, status, err) {
        this.setState({ data: comments });
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this));
   },
   onUpdateComment: function(id, comment) {
     // clone state, we don't want to alter this directly
     var newData = this.state.data.slice(0);
     newData.forEach(function(item) {
       if(item.id === id) {
         item.text = comment;
       }
     });
     $.ajax({
       url: this.props.url,
       dataType: 'json',
       method: 'PATCH',
       data: newData
     }).then(function(data) {
       this.setState({ data: data });
     }.bind(this));
   },
   getInitialState: function() { 
     return {data: []}; 
   }, 
   componentDidMount: function() { 
     this.loadCommentsFromServer(); 
     setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval); 
   }, 
   render: function() { 
     return ( 
       <div className="commentBox"> 
         <h1>Comments</h1> 
         <CommentList data={this.state.data} /> 
         <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} /> 
       </div> 
     ); 
   } 
 });
```